# how to play the video in its original form without distortion and stretching in CircleGeometry in three js?

Tags: three.js, augmented-reality, threejs-editor, mindar

how to play the video in its original form without distortion and stretching in CircleGeometry in three js.
when we scan the target, how to render the video without stretching in CircleGeometry in three js.

```
texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
texture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

 // Create a material using the texture
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });
```